# What is use of Json.stringify() and without stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here i'm new to Jquery Please Help me

```
 var obj={"FirstName":'Hussain','LastName':'Ali','MiddleName':'Zain'}

    $('#jsonConvert').click(function () {

        var Objected = JSON.stringify(obj);
        console.log(Objected);
        var Raw = obj;
        console.log(Raw);
    })
```

When i Convert `.Stringify()` its Give me same result as of `Raw` Then what is use of .Stringify();
If i want  Only FirstName then how can i get

Comment: check `typeof Objected` and `typeof Raw`

Comment: Do those console.log results really look the same? What browser are you using?

Comment: [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify): It converts JavaScript values to JSON.

Comment: When i convert its into Json Then how can i Get FirstName  When i Use as  var Objected = JSON.stringify(obj);
        console.log(Objected.FirstName);   its gives me undefind

Comment: JSON is a `String` you have to parse it again. Your question makes no sense. See the duplicate.

Comment: @Roberson could u please give me any example their i can learn

Comment: @MdGhousemohi Just use `obj.FirstName`. Don't convert `obj` to JSON...

Comment: @MdGhousemohi [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON.Stringify will convert your JSON **object** into string and notice the word ***object***.

Meaning is you receive an object of json:

```
var obj = {
  "FirstName": 'Hussain',
  'LastName': 'Ali',
  'MiddleName': 'Zain'
};
```

And you want to send it to the server as string, you use:

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

The result is:

```
"{
      "FirstName": "Hussain",
      "LastName": "Ali",
      "MiddleName": "Zain"
    }"
```

The opposite is `JSON.parse()`, it will convert a valid JSON **string** into json object and notice the word ***valid JSON string***. If you try to parse object to object, you will get an error "Unexpected type O at location zero" or any other random error of that sort. Meaning:

Meaning is you receive a string of json:

```
  var obj = "{
  "FirstName": "Hussain",
  "LastName": "Ali",
  "MiddleName": "Zain"
}"
```

And you use it by parsing it into object:

```
JSON.parse(obj).FirstName;
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: JavaScript - Object - Notation -_-

Comment: It's either a string (JSON) or a key-value-pair data structure (object). But not both at the same time, hence... There's no such thing as a "JSON object"

Comment: A string is an object, pure and simple.

Comment: people are mistaking string all the time, there is no such a thing string, there never was. A string is an array of chars. The string class just creates a wrapper so developers won't tear their hairs off when trying to write full string sentences (C language hmm...). A string is an object, reference type that behaves like a value type.

Comment: HEY I got it, it was leaving the USER_ID param blank! The server needed a value and couldn't take a blank value. JEEZ, I can't believe it!

Answer (score 0):

To get `FirstName`, you only use `obj.FirstName`:

```js
var obj = {
  "FirstName": 'Hussain',
  'LastName': 'Ali',
  'MiddleName': 'Zain'
};
console.log(obj.FirstName);
console.log(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // this will give you a string that follows the JSON notations
```

The `JSON.stringify` method basically converts a JavaScript value into a JSON string. Typically used to convert JavaScript arrays or objects to JSON.

Example:

```js
var someArray = ['Hello', 'World', 123, true];
var json = JSON.stringify(someArray);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: i ask what is the Use of .Stringify()  f